# a number range with probability

Tags: python

A way for getting a number from a range with probability

let's say a number range between `1 - 5` and has a distribution of `[.50, .30, .10, .07, .03]`  1 has a `50%` percent chance of being returned it's easy but it's only viable for small numbers(`random.choices([1, 2, 3, 4,5], [.50, .30, .10, .07, .03])`), this time lets say the range is between `1 - 100` and that the numbers in the range `1 - 40` only gets returned `20%` of the time and so on and so forth.

the probability of the number range of `1 - 100`

```
1 - 40   10%
41 - 60  35%
61 - 70  25%
71 - 80  15%
81 - 90  10%
91 - 95   4%
96 - 100  1%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

thing = [(10, 40), (41, 60), (61, 70), (71, 80), (81, 90), (91, 95), (96, 100)]
prob = [.10, .35, .25, .15, .10, .04, .01]


[(start, stop)] = random.choices(thing, prob)

num = random.randrange(start, stop + 1, 1)
print(num)
```

i was about to ask this question but realized it was actually easy

Comment: You could just do `start, stop = random.choices(thing, prob)`, no need of string replacing or integer conversion.

Comment: Sorry, that would be `[(start, stop)] = random.choices(thing, prob)`. You can see it running [here](https://tio.run/##Vc49DsMgDAXgnVN4BAkhaMjf0JNEGdK0ahgCiHjp6Sl2py5Pnyy9J@cPHil2tYYzp4JQtvhMpxB4hPiGOyzSWQ3eKg3SOw0Da2gaWWPTxJqaZtZM6lmDBmetWkUu6UFzhuZM17e4UTgOullP4VYhFnnhVlDDhSmrtdV@X5n9SGF/XZKf00Cbqi2HiH@NWr8).

Comment: Wow, I actually learned something very useful Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.choices` with the weights to select a range, and then `random.choice` to select a random number from that range.  I'd set up the `choices` call with a `zip`ped series of tuples to make it easy to associate the ranges with the probabilities:

```
>>> random.choice(random.choices(*zip(
...     (range(1, 41), 10),
...     (range(41, 61), 35),
...     (range(61, 71), 25),
...     (range(71, 81), 15),
...     (range(81, 91), 10),
...     (range(91, 96), 4),
...     (range(96, 101), 1),
... ))[0])
65
```